# what is the use of creating proxy for an webservice

Tags: web-services

i have an webserivce  written where i do an insertion opertion to DB.
path :http://localhost:1838/Ajax/WebService.asmx?wsdl.name of the webservice is **localhost**
i have added webservice for the project

now on button click event i try to call this webserice like this
**localhost obj= new localhost();
obj.insert();**
now i am able to do the insertion operation fine.

but i wanted to create an proxy for the webservice so wat is the use of it doing like tat?

when i run this command in my command prompt  in vs

wsdl /out:myProxyClass.cs http://localhost:1838/Ajax/WebService.asmx?WSDL

**i get an error**

1. unable to connect the remote server.
2. no connection would be made because
       the target machine actively refused
       it

looking forward for an solution any help would great

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the built in develoment webserver (Cassini). Are you sure it was running when you issued the wsdl command ? The tool needs to connect to the service and download metadata, in order to generate your proxy.